# Prove that $x_0$ is Lyapunov unstable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

> Let $X : U \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ vector field and $x_0$ a singular point F $(i.e., X(x_0)=0)$. Let $h : V \to \mathbb R$ be  a $C^1$ map defined on neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $x_0$ such that $h(x_0) = 0 $ and such that $\dot{h}(x) = \frac{d}{dt}h(\varphi(t,x))|_{t=0}>0$ for every $x \in V\setminus\{x_0\}$ (where by $\varphi(t,x)$ we denote the solution for $x'=X(x)$, $x(0) = x$). Suppose that for every neighborhood $W \subset V$ of $x_0$ there is $\tilde x \in W$ such that $h(\tilde x)>0$. Prove that $x_0$ is Lyapunov unstable.

I'll show  what I've done so far: we suppose that $x_0$ is stable. We choose a compact neighborhood $V_0$ of $x_0$, since it is stable, then there exists an neighborhood $x_0\in V_1\subset V_0$ such that for any $x\in V_1$  we have $\varphi(t,x)\in V_0$ for every $t\geq 0$. By hypothesis we have $h(x)>0$ and since the positive semi-orbit of $x$ is such that $\varphi(t,x)\in V_0$ and $V_0$ is compact, then $\omega(x)\neq \emptyset$, compact and it is invariant (ie, $y\in \omega(x) \implies \varphi(t,y)\in \omega(x))$.

Now how to proceed? I've tried to use the fact that $\omega(x)$ is compact and hence $h$ would have a maximum at $\omega(x)$ and that didn't work. Any ideas, any help?

Comment: Do you mean "singular point" as in, the vector field there is undefined and discontinuous, or do you mean "stationary point" as in the vector field is zero there?

Comment: @LutzL I mean $X(x_0)=0$

Comment: This might help (p. 92 of Arrowsmith & Place): https://books.google.com/books?id=8qCcP7KNaZ0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=en#v=onepage&q=92&f=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the structure of [Arrowsmith & Place: *"Dynamical systems ..."*, p92](https://books.google.de/books?id=8qCcP7KNaZ0C&pg=PA92)

Select some $R>r>0$ and some $x_1\in B(x_0,r)$ with $h(x_1)>0$. Then there is some neighborhood $U$ around $x_0$ where $h(x)<h(x_1)/2$ for all $x\in U$. As $h(φ(x_1,t))$ is an increasing function, this trajectory stays outside $U$.

Now $\bar B(x_0,R)\setminus U$ is a closed and thus compact set, the positive continuous function $\nabla h\cdot X$ has a positive minimum $K$ there. As long as the trajectory $φ(x_1,t)$ stays inside $\bar B(x_0,R)$, we conclude that $h(φ(x_1,t))\ge h(x_1)+Kt$. As $h$ is bounded on the compact set $\bar B(x_0,R)$, the trajectory has to leave this closed ball around $x_0$ of radius $R$.

Thus $x_0$ is unstable, as $r>0$ can be arbitrarily small and $R>r$ arbitrarily large.